# I need help with this definition of a category from SEP

Tags: category-theory

I need help with this definition from "Category Theory" at [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/):

[image]

According to the article, "This is the definition one finds in most textbooks of category theory."

1. Let's start with the first sentence. Does it mean that $Ob \subset C$?
2. If so, what else might be in $C$?
3. In the second sentence, are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be elements of $Ob$?
4. Is a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ the same as a function mapping elements of $X$ to elements of $Y$?

Comment: First, this definition they're offering is pretty terrible and confusing. And there are way better resources for understanding a category (e.g. even Wikipedia does a better job than that.) In addition, the claim "this is the definition one finds in most textbooks of category theory" is false; most reasonable people will not call the collection of objects $Ob(\mathcal{C})$ a set, but rather a **class**, because many large collections of objects we care about are generally not sets (e.g. **Set** is a category whose objects consists of all sets,  and such a collection is itself not a set).

Comment: I agree with @trujello, just look for a different definition. This one is excessively confusing for no good reason. Most treatments will not even introduce the notion of a Hom-set until it's needed, usually quite a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a category is twofold. If we want to say that something is a category you need to specify the objects your category consists of together with the morphisms between them. So in a way, one can identify a category $\mathbf{C}$ with its "class" of objects $\textbf{Ob}$. However by doing that you are not specifying the morphisms, so people usually write "let $X \in \mathbf{C}$" instead of "let $X \in \textbf{Ob}$" when it is clear which category we are working with.

This means that no, $\textbf{Ob}$ is not a subset of $\mathbf{C}$. Object-wise we have that $\textbf{Ob}$ *is* $\mathbf{C}$, so there is no more stuff outside $\mathbf{Ob}$.

Next, a category consists of, *for each pair of objects $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbf{Ob}$*, a set $\textbf{Hom}(X,Y)$, so this means that yes, given a morphism $f \colon X \to Y$ in your category, both the target and the source are objects in your category.

Your fourth question has a negative answer however. Although it is true that in the first examples of categories that come to mind the objects are "sets plus extra information" (think of the category of sets, groups, abelian groups, topological spaces, etcetera), it is not true in general that an object in an arbitrary category has the underlying structure of a set. Therefore it doesn't make sense to talk about elements of an object at all.

Maybe this is better explained with an example. Let $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{1}$ denote the category whose only object is the symbol $\star$ and the identity morphism $\text{id}_{\star}$ is the only morphism. This is a category, but notice that $\star$ is not a set and hence the (unique) morphism in this category can't be thought of as function mapping elements of $\star$ to itself.

$$ \star \to \bullet$$
is another category, where I've omitted the identity arrows for $\star$ and $\bullet$, provided that the morphism $\star \to \bullet$ respects the identity axiom. Again the only morphism that is not the identity is not a function between sets, since $\star$ and $\bullet$ might not be sets to begin with.

Finally, I would like to address part of the set-theoretical difficulties that appear inevitably when dealing with categories. We want to be able to work with categories such as $\textbf{Sets}$, whose objects are sets and the set of morphisms $\textbf{Hom}(X,Y)$ for any two sets $X$ and $Y$ are functions between sets. Then, what "thing" is $\textbf{Ob}$ in this category? It can't be a set since Russell's paradox shows the inconsistency of allowing a "set of all sets". One way to get rid of this difficulty is to allow classes, and to work in an axiomatic set theory that has this notion, so that one says "$\textbf{Ob}$ is a class".

Another possibility which I personally find cleaner is to fix what is known as a [Grothendieck Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) $\mathcal{U}$ and talk about the category of $\mathcal{U}$-sets, $\mathcal{U}$-groups, etcetera. Anyway, this is more a matter of preference, I'd say.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Slightly off topic, but in your opinion, would there be any pedagogical value in a "baby" category theory for, say, advanced high school students, one based on sets alone to give students a taste of category theory?

Comment: @DanChristensen Personally I think that the beauty and usefulness of category theory lies in its simplicity to connect several concepts in Mathematics, and in order to see that, one needs a decent amount of knowledge in these areas. I'd find difficult to introduce the notion of a coproduct, for example, if people don't know what a free product of groups is. I would also have problems motivating the definition of a functor if my audience doesn't know what the fundamental group is. Undergraduate students? Sure. But I'm not sure how high-school students would benefit from category theory.

Comment: @user313212 I don't know either of those things and had no trouble understanding the notion of coproduct or functor. Granted, I'm a professional scientist and quite far from being a high school student - I agree it takes a certain amount of experience to see the value of category theory, at least the way it's currently usually developed.